# Img tag can't access an object for the src

Tags: reactjs, object, fetch, src

In this React component, I am trying to set an object as the URL for the `Img`'s `src`. However, I kept getting the error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'front_default' of undefined (/App.js:33)`. This is in a [Scrimba](https://scrimba.com/p/p7P5Hd/co417-f762261f433f) course

```
import React, {Component} from "react"
class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            loading: false,
            character: {}
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({loading: true})
        fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-form/1")
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                this.setState({
                    loading: false,
                    character: data
                })
            console.log(this.state.character.name)
            console.log(this.state.character.sprites.front_default)
            })      
    } 
    render() {
        const text = this.state.loading ? "loading..." : this.state.character.name
        let frontSprite = this.state.loading ? "Loading..." : this.state.character.sprites.front_default 
        // The url that the img should get: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/back/shiny/1.png"
        return (
            <div>
                <img src={frontSprite}/> 
                <p>{text}</p>
                <p>{frontSprite}</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default App
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to create a new state called `front_default`, which will store the url of `this.state.character.sprites.front_default`. After the data is fetched, `front_default` equaled to whatever the URL was.

```
import React, {Component} from "react"
class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            loading: false,
            character: {},
            front_default: "",
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({loading: true})
        fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-form/1")
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                this.setState({
                    loading: false,
                    character: data,
                    front_default: data.sprites.front_default
                })
            console.log(this.state.character.name)
            })      
    }

    render() {
        const text = this.state.loading ? "loading..." : this.state.character.name
        let frontSprite = this.state.loading ? "Loading..." : this.state.front_default 
        // The url that the img should get: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/back/shiny/1.png"
        return (
            <div>
                <img src={frontSprite}/> 
                <p>{text}</p>
                <p>{frontSprite}</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default App
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to the object reference is undefined. This could be because of the React **life cycle function** *componentDidMount* which did not do re-render after the fetch operation.

I have made the following changes in the code, which worked fine.

```
let text = this.state.loading ? "loading..." : this.state.character.name;
let sprites = this.state.loading ? "loading...": this.state.character.sprites;

let front_default = "";
if(sprites && sprites !== "loadding..."){
  front_default = sprites['front_default'];
}
```

Find the attached snapshot of the result. [Code execution snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6A5S.png)

**Suggestion:**

You can use the React Hooks `useState` and `useEffect` instead of `componentDidMount()`

Comment: But, then `this.state.character.name`, should not work either.

Comment: Also, I tried the snippet and the did not work too.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error, because the initial state is `loading: false`.

On your first render (before you set `loading: true` for the API call) it will try to render.

Thus `let frontSprite = this.state.loading ? "Loading..." : this.state.character.sprites.front_default` will fail because the initial value of `this.state.character` is `{}` and `{}.sprites` gives undefined leading to the error.

To solve this, you could do an early return when `character: {}`.

Comment: Oh thank you, I did not realize that it was rendering `frontSprite` too early...

Comment: But, then `this.state.character.name`, should not work either.